# OctoberCMS: How to check if a js file has been already included by another widget

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, octobercms-widgets

I have got two [Report Widget](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/widgets#report-widgets) classes both of which use `highcharts.js` library. So both of them should include `highcharts.js` before being rendered. Therefore they implement the `loadAssets` method:

```
public function loadAssets()
{
    $this->addJs('js/highcharts.js');
}
```

The problem is that I should not call `addJs` method if another report widget has already been added to the page, otherwise `highcharts.js` will be included in the backend dashboard twice. How can I check to avoid adding the js file multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

When using the `addJs()` and `addCss()` functions, October itself checks if the asset is already loaded and if it is, it is not loaded again.

Comment: This is only true for multiple instances of the same report widget. If you have two instances of two separate widgets, they wont be able to know that a javascript file has already been included. Try it!

Comment: I'm using 5 different report widgets and 3 js files are loaded in each widget.

Although I'm calling the `addJs()` in the widgets `render()` function. This way the assets are not loaded multiple times.